# Create Mesos role via REST API

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

Is there a way to create `Mesos` role using `roles` endpoint? I've tried different combinations of `PUT / POST` requests to `http://mesos_master_url:5050/roles` with different `JSON` body messages like

```
{
  "frameworks":[],
  "name":"new-role",
  "resources":{
    "cpus":0,
    "disk":0,
    "gpus":0,
    "mem":0
  },
  "weight":1.0
}
```

but with no success. The [docs itself](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/master/roles/) are not that useful.

Answer (score 2):

Roles is a part of resource definition and it must be done on node level. New role is declared when there is at least one resource attached to it.

To assign resource to specific role put role name after the resource in brackets. For example we want to run roles development and test on one cluster. We want to distinguish ports offered to these roles. The development tasks will be run on ports `31000-32000` and be tested on `41000-42000`. To do it we define following resources.

```
ports(develop):[31000-32000]; ports(test):[41000-42000]
```

See [Roles documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/roles/) and [resources](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/attributes-resources/)

Answer (score 0):

Also, roles are actually created on the mesos masters.

Generally, the config lives in `/etc/mesos-master/roles` and the content is like this:

```
 role1,role2,role3,role4,role5,...,roleN
```